# TCL line parsing with escape chars

Tags: regex, tcl

An observation and question.

Given a textfile with lines which include escape characters. I.e. backslash. Parsing those lines and separating content using `lindex` and `lassign` eat away the escape characters. This is a semi question. I suspect that in TCL the assignment includes parsing of the target object and thus processing of the escape chars. Wondering if there is a way around it.

My observation is that only regex was able to pull the line apart without processing.

I'm sure the forum text editor will garble my test file. (Oh well, it didn't)

```
% cat lines.txt
1 a/b/c/d[7]
2 a/b\/c\/d\[7\]
3 a\/b/c/d[7]

set fp [ open lines.txt ]
set rpt [ read $fp ]
close $fp

foreach line [ split $rpt \n ] {
    set val [ lindex $line 0 ]
    set str [ lindex $line 1 ]
    puts "val= $val : str= $str"
}

val= 1 : str= a/b/c/d[7]
val= 2 : str= a/b/c/d[7]
val= 3 : str= a/b/c/d[7]
val=  : str=

foreach line [ split $rpt \n ] {
    lassign $line val str
    puts "val= $val : str= $str"
}

val= 1 : str= a/b/c/d[7]
val= 2 : str= a/b/c/d[7]
val= 3 : str= a/b/c/d[7]
val=  : str=

foreach line [ split $rpt \n ] {
    regexp {(\S+)\s+(\S+)} $line dmy val str
    puts "val= $val : str= $str"
}

val= 1 : str= a/b/c/d[7]
val= 2 : str= a/b\/c\/d\[7\]
val= 3 : str= a\/b/c/d[7]
val= 3 : str= a\/b/c/d[7]
```

Comment: This is really the main Tcl unwritten rule-of-thumb: don't use list commands on strings.

Comment: And it is not the assignment, but rather the conversion of the string to a list which happens when lindex is applied to the string that "eats away" the Tcl meta characters. It helps to remember that, in Tcl, type is coerced by commands not variables and that lists are specially formatted strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used regexp. It seems to avoid the string parsing and works on a lower level to pick the line apart.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to use `split` to break the line into fields on whitespace, rather than assuming it's a well-formed tcl list.

```
foreach line [ split $rpt \n ] {
    lassign [split $line " "] val str
    puts "val= $val : str= $str"
}
```

If that doesn't work because there can be more than one whitespace character between fields, you can use `splitx` which splits on a regex instead of a simple character:

```
package require textutil::split
foreach line [ split $rpt \n ] {
    lassign [textutil::split::splitx $line] val str
    puts "val= $val : str= $str"
}
```

Comment: A minor: `split $line " "` could be reduced to `split $line`, as the default split char is whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main commands for parsing an *arbitrary* string into a list:

1. `regexp -inline` (often with `-all`): this is often my favourite these days as I can just describe the RE rule for what a word is and have it do the rest of the work for me.
2. `split` provided you want what it does: sometimes it is possible to precondition the string (using unusual unicode characters) to make this work better, but I don't like it myself.
3. `scan` *without* variables: **everyone** forgets this one, myself included...

You can also do things yourself piecemeal (or use a library function that handles the details, such as `textutil::splitx`).

---

The list operations themselves don't work with arbitrary strings, but rather only those strings that follow the list format rules. Backslashes are special in those rules (just like they are in your script). So are `{`curly  braces`}`. The usual recommendation is to not treat arbitrary external data as a Tcl list, and is because it usually works on test data and all too often goes subtly wrong in production (but not straight away). Pre-cleaning the data saves much head scratching.